# Creating a "wall" node in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I'm working with SpriteKit, Xcode 6 and Swift

I have a spritenode declared like this:

```
let firstCircle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")
firstCircle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 7)
firstCircle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
```

and another spritenode which is bigger circle declared like this :

```
let wall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")
wall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 50)
wall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
```

The node `firstcircle` follows my finger and the node `wall` stay at the middle of the screen, and I want that the two nodes cannot enter in collision together, but with my actual code, `firstcircle` just cross the `wall`, what have I to do in order to fix that problem ?

Here is how I move the node :

```
let scale:CGFloat = 10.0
let damping:CGFloat = 0.94

var departCircleLocation = CGPoint()
var departTouchLocation = CGPoint()
var currentTouchLocation = CGPoint()
var isTouchActive = false

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
{
    isTouchActive = true

    for touch: AnyObject in touches
    {
        departTouchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    }

    departCircleLocation = firstCircle.position
    currentTouchLocation = departTouchLocation
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
{
    for touch: AnyObject in touches
    {
        currentTouchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    }

    moveCircles()
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
{
    isTouchActive = false
}

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval)
{
    moveCircle()
}

func moveCircle()
{        
    if isTouchActive
    {
        var dx = CGFloat(departCircleLocation.x - departTouchLocation.x + currentTouchLocation.x - firstCircle.position.x) * scale
        var dy = CGFloat(departCircleLocation.y - departTouchLocation.y + currentTouchLocation.y - firstCircle.position.y) * scale
        firstCircle.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(dx, dy)
    }
    else
    {
        let dx = firstCircle.physicsBody!.velocity.dx * damping
        let dy = firstCircle.physicsBody!.velocity.dy * damping
        firstCircle.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(dx, dy)    
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to correct your posted code. You define `wall`, but then configure another circle. Confusing.

Comment: You are right, I put the name "wall" for more comprehension, I edited my post

Comment: The wall is a circle? You write it is a rectangle, but you define a circle. Confusing.

Comment: Show how you move the node. If you just set the node's position it will not show proper physics behavior because you force the node to be at that position, regardless of whether physics would consider that position within a collision or not. If you want physics behavior, apply impulse/force or set velocity directly, but you can't just assign to the node's position or rotation.

Comment: I move the node by changing his velocity, so it should work

Comment: Do you want the circle node to move over the wall node without affecting it or do you want the circle node to bounce off of the wall node?

Comment: I just realized my mistake, the sprite of the wall was way too big, his radius was 80pixels, and I thought it was only 50, so I put SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 50), and my node disappeared behind this wall and there were a collision with a smaller circle, but I couldn't see it due to the sprite of the bigger wall so I thought the collisions weren't working !

Comment: i can also recommend you using the spritekit editor. this site has a great starter tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/118225/introduction-sprite-kit-scene-editor